# How to perform multiple group to get the total average?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have the following table,

```
S.No    Date,Time            Block        OccupancyActual        OccupancyPercentage
1       1/1/2020,00:00       B1           300                    40%    
2       1/1/2020,01:00       B1           350                    46.6%    
3       1/1/2020,02:00       B1           400                    53.3%    
4       1/1/2020,00:00       B2           200                    50%    
5       1/1/2020,01:00       B2           300                    75%    
6       1/1/2020,02:00       B2           350                    87.5%    
7       2/1/2020,00:00       B1           100                    13.3%    
8       2/1/2020,01:00       B1           200                    26.6%    
.
.
.
```

Basically this table captures the occupancy of each block(B1,B2,B3,etc) per hour(24 entries per day, but have not mentioned fully above).

Each row contains the name of the block and the number of units in the block at that time, and the percentage full of the block([no of blocks in it/total capacity of block] as a %)

The average total occupancy of the entire yard **per day** is the sum of the average occupancies of each block(of the 24 entries for each block), and the total capacity of the entire yard is the sum of the total capacities of each of the blocks.

Can you please help me write a postgre sql query to get the average occupancy of the yard per day? Something similar to,

```
S.No    Date                 OccupancyTotalActual        OccupancyPercentage
1       1/1/2020             6000                        40%    
2       2/1/2020             5000                        33.3%    
3       3/1/2020             2500                        16.6%    
.
.
.
```

Comment: What is a "yard"?  What is "the sum of the average occupancies of each block"?

Comment: Yard is a collection of blocks, each of which have multiple boxes in them.. the boxes present constitute to the occupancy.. the capacity is the max number of boxes the block can hold..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . Does this logic do what you want?

```
select date_trunc(day, datetime),
       sum(OccupancyActual),
       sum(OccupancyActual) / sum(OccupancyActual / OccupancyPercentage) as OccupancyRatio
from t
group by date_trunc(day, datetime);
```

Comment: yes, it seems to give me the results.. i havent yet checked if the results are right.. but i dont understand how this calculates it.. can you please elaborate? that would be really helpful..

Comment: @codeworks . . . The query seems pretty clear to me.  It is an aggregation query.  You might want to look at the separate results form `sum(OccupancyActual)` and `sum(OccupancyActual / OccupancyPercentage)`.